# Redirecting pages in Wordpress with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have created a Wordpress site that is an updated version of an old website. The old website has already have some links high in google search and I want to create redirection in htaccess form the old pages to new ones (domain stays the same). For example I have a link like this

```
/index.php?event=newsdetails&news_id=139&parent_id=4&menu_id=1
```

and I want to redirect it to this

```
/blog/my/link
```

How I can do that? Is it posibble to do it so it will work on any domain (for example the new site is right now on a test domain)?
Here is my htaccess file, but it's not working the way I want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?pchig\.pl$ [NC]
#RewriteRule !^pl/ /pl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

#Redirections
RewriteRule ^/index.php?event=newsdetails&news_id=140&parent_id=4&menu_id=1(\/.*)?$ /blog/my/link [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What is /blog/my/link? That is not clear. Is `blog` a subdirectory? Don't put examples like `/blog/my/link`, that's not helpful. Put exactly how you expect the link to look like in the browser for the new site in your question.

Comment: The new link should be a permalink. For example /blog/new-year-in-china

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a 301 redirect into your .htaccess file:

```
redirect 301 /old/old.html http://www.new.com/new.html
```

Notes: Don't add "http://www" to the first part of the
statement - place the path from the top level of your site
to the page. Also ensure that you leave a single space
between these elements:

redirect 301 (the instruction that the page has moved)

/old/old.htm (the original folder path and file name)

http://www.new.com/new.htm (new path and file name)

When the search engines spider your site again they will
follow the rule you have created in your .htaccess file.
The search engine spider doesn't actually read the 
.htaccess file, but recognizes the response from the 
server as valid.

During the next update, the old file name and path will be
dropped and replaced with the new one. Sometimes you may
see alternating old/new file names during the transition
period, plus some fluctuations in rankings. According to
Google it will take 6-8 weeks to see the changes reflected
on your pages.

---

If you want to redirect ALL files on your domain use this in your
.htaccess file if you are on a unix web server:

```
redirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com 
redirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com
```

You can also use one of these in your .htaccess file:

```
redirect 301 /index.html http://www.example.com/index.html 
redirect permanent /index.html http://www.example.com/index.html 
redirectpermanent /index.html http://www.example.com/index.html
```

This will redirect "index.html" to another domain using a
301-Moved permanently redirect.

If you need to redirect http://example.com to
http://www.example.com and you've got mod_rewrite enabled on
your server you can put this in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

or this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exmaple.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```